# How to check Golden Gate Lag or Syncing status?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I'm trying below query to get the result but is there any other way possible to get real time golden gate syncing status?

```
SELECT delgroup,
     EXTRACT (DAY FROM SYSTIMESTAMP - update_timestamp) * 24 * 3600
   + EXTRACT (HOUR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP - update_timestamp) * 3600
   + EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM SYSTIMESTAMP - update_timestamp) * 60
   + EXTRACT (SECOND FROM SYSTIMESTAMP - source_commit)
      lag_update,totallag
```

FROM GG_LOAD.GGS_HEARTBEAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will give the lag status.

```
SELECT delgroup,
     EXTRACT (DAY FROM SYSTIMESTAMP - update_timestamp) * 24 * 3600
   + EXTRACT (HOUR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP - update_timestamp) * 3600
   + EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM SYSTIMESTAMP - update_timestamp) * 60
   + EXTRACT (SECOND FROM SYSTIMESTAMP - source_commit)
      lag_update,totallag
```

Answer (score 1):

You can login into the ggs utility and give

GGSCI> Info replicat  (or) info all -> for all extracts/replicat status

In the results you can see a column name "lag at chkpt" where you will see lag if there is issue in the sync.